# Book series about interstellar spaceship from the 90s

Tags: story-identification, books

In the late 90s I read a series of 3-4 books about a woman who was assigned to work on an interstellar spacecraft. I dimly recall the ship was round. The existing crew of the ship threw a party that had people dressed up as Daleks, Buck Rogers, and other Sci-Fi heroes/villains for people that were going out of the solar system for the first time.

I want to say there was some form of law enforcement agent that she ends up in a relationship with (I think he was described as leonine or lion-like), and I believe the later books have the woman and the law enforcement agent end up on a planet.